# LLVM error when creating array

Tags: cuda, llvm, ptx

I want to add the following line to my llvm code (as specified in the [ptx backend documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/NVPTXUsage.html)):

```
%1 = internal addrspace(3) global [4 x i32] [ i32 0, i32 1, i32 2, i32 3 ]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
expected instruction opcode
@g = internal addrspace(3) global [4 x i32] [ i32 0, i32 1, i32 2, i32 3 ]
^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you want to add and the line on which the error is reported are not the same - I'm guessing a copy-paste error?

In any case, the first line is illegal, because you're defining a global with a local name (starting with `%` instead of `@`). The second line is legal by itself but from the error message I'm guessing you tried to write it inside a function, which is not a legal location for a global. Just like globals in C, LLVM globals need to be defined directly in the module scope, outside any function definition.

Comment: It was indeed a copy-paste error (I tried both and got an error for both). But the problem was indeed defining a global in function scope. Thanks!